# ASP.NET 4 release?

Tags: asp.net

When will ASP.NET 4.0 be released?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There will surely be more news on this during [Microsoft Mix](http://visitmix.com/) ( Also [Here](http://www.microsoft.com/events/mix/default.aspx) ) next week.

Answer (score 0):

Together with the rest f the .NET framewrk 4.0 - PROBABLY (there is nothing official) in the MAY timeframe. Original was planned 12th of April, then got pushed back "a couple of weeks". Given they are in RC state, Mid to End of May seems like a decent estimate. It is, though, nothing more than an estimate from my side.